# Allow - (dash) in regular expression

Tags: asp.net, regex

I have the following regular expression but I want the text box to allow the dash character

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z \/_?:.,\s]+$
```

Anyone know how I can do this?

Answer (score 86, accepted):

The dash needs to be the first/last character in the character class in order to be used literally:

```
^[-0-9a-zA-Z \/_?:.,\s]+$

^[0-9a-zA-Z \/_?:.,\s-]+$
```

You could also escape it, if not the first/last:

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z\- \/_?:.,\s]+$
```

Comment: or the last or needs to be escaped, but anyway +1

Comment: @stema - Thanks for that. Didn't know about it being last also working. Answer updated.

Comment: It seems, its also working if the dash is the first character after a range see `[A-C-Z]` [example on Regexr](http://regexr.com?2vmvh) this class is only matching A-C, - and Z. (But I wouldn't use this, its a bit unreadable.)

Comment: @stema - That does look completely unreadable... or very confusing at the least.

Comment: As I wrote, I wouldn't use it.

Answer (score 5):

Simple answer, user `\-` in character class.

```
^[0-9a-zA-Z\- \/_?:.,\s]+$
```

Answer (score 1):

Escape it with \ like:

```
^[\-0-9a-zA-Z \/_?:.,\s]+$
```