# Preg Match Not Working

Tags: php, preg-match

I am working to check Username with preg_match, but i do something wrong, only i dont know what i do wrong, i did try many times, but without success, so if u can help me, thank you very much and its also a good lesson for me. This is my source what i am doing:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
  {
?>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="config.php?name=<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>&amp;gender=<?php echo $_POST['gender']; ?>&amp;color=<?php echo $_POST['color']; ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Applet Start -->
<br /><div style="text-align: center;">
<div id="lightIRC" style="height:500px; text-align:center;"><p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" title="Get flash player"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p></div>

<script type="text/javascript">swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.futurechat.nl/chat/lightIRC.swf", "lightIRC", "100%", "500", "10.0.0", "http://www.futurechat.nl/chat/expressInstall.swf", params);</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
  else {
  print_form();
}
function print_form() {
// MAKE SURE USERNAME IS ALPHANUMERIC
$name = $_POST['name'];
if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/', $_POST['name']))
  echo "Invalid Username";
?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<style>
body {font-family: Verdana;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<form action="chatlogin.php" method="post">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="background: #cccccc;text-align: center;font-size: 13px;">
<tr valign="top">
<td>
Nickname: 
<input type="text" name="name">
<br /><br />
Gender: 
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
<br /><br />
Applet Color: 
<select name="color">
  <option value="lightblue">Lightblue</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="darkorange">Dark Orange</option>
  <option value="black">Black</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="pink">Pink</option>
  <option value="white">White</option>
</select> 
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Chat now!">
</td>
</tr></table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php
}
?>
```

Comment: You probably want to move `print_form();` into the if-block instead of the else. As it is right now, `$_POST['name']` will always be null.

Comment: @alexn what do you mean with this? Can you show a example? Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Are you looking at the source code when you have `$_POST['name']` set?  It looks like you are printing `Invalid Username` at the VERY top of the document, above the `<html>` tag, which is why it will not show up in the browser (because it's not valid HTML).  You should be storing the error message and printing it inside your HTML, or move the logic inside your HTML (surrounded by `<?php` and `?>` tags)

Try this code:

```
<?php
$ValidUsername = true;
if(isset($_POST['submit'])) {
    // MAKE SURE USERNAME IS ALPHANUMERIC
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/', $name))
      $ValidUsername = false;
}
?>
<?php if(isset($_POST['submit']) && $ValidUsername): ?>
<html>
<head>
<script language="javascript" src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/swfobject/2.2/swfobject.js" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script language="javascript" src="config.php?name=<?php echo $_POST['name']; ?>&amp;gender=<?php echo $_POST['gender']; ?>&amp;color=<?php echo $_POST['color']; ?>" type="text/javascript"></script>
</head>
<body>
<!-- Applet Start -->
<br /><div style="text-align: center;">
<div id="lightIRC" style="height:500px; text-align:center;"><p><a href="http://www.adobe.com/go/getflashplayer" title="Get flash player"><img src="http://www.adobe.com/images/shared/download_buttons/get_flash_player.gif" alt="Get Adobe Flash player" /></a></p></div>

<script type="text/javascript">swfobject.embedSWF("http://www.futurechat.nl/chat/lightIRC.swf", "lightIRC", "100%", "500", "10.0.0", "http://www.futurechat.nl/chat/expressInstall.swf", params);</script>
</div>
</body>
</html>

<?php else: ?>

<html>
<head>
<title>Login</title>
<style>
body {font-family: Verdana;}
</style>
</head>
<body>
<?php
if (!$ValidUsername)
    echo "<h1>Invalid Username</h1>";
?>
<form action="chatlogin.php" method="post">
<table cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" align="center" style="background: #cccccc;text-align: center;font-size: 13px;">
<tr valign="top">
<td>
Nickname: 
<input type="text" name="name">
<br /><br />
Gender: 
<input type="radio" name="gender" value="Male">Male <input type="radio" name="gender" value="Female">Female
<br /><br />
Applet Color: 
<select name="color">
  <option value="lightblue">Lightblue</option>
  <option value="blue">Blue</option>
  <option value="darkorange">Dark Orange</option>
  <option value="black">Black</option>
  <option value="yellow">Yellow</option>
  <option value="green">Green</option>
  <option value="pink">Pink</option>
  <option value="white">White</option>
</select> 
<br /><br />
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Chat now!">
</td>
</tr></table>
</form>
</body>
</html>
<?php endif; ?>
```

This code uses [Alternate Syntax](http://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.alternative-syntax.php) for encapsulating HTML code.  I believe it is easier to read...

Comment: i want to check usernames on illegal characters before he go to the chat, but i did try set him lower, above this

<tr valign="top">
<?php // MAKE SURE USERNAME IS ALPHANUMERIC
$name = $_POST['name'];
if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/', $_POST['name']))
  echo "Invalid Username";
?>
<td>
Nickname: 
<input type="text" name="name">

But it doenst work.

Comment: i did try that code, but he go to the chat with illegal characters, so i dont think that he does check.

Comment: Updated code for what you needed, it checked in the wrong place

Comment: i also did try your code about Alternate Syntax, but i got blank page with this. The meaning is, When a user type their username in text field (input), he must allow only charachters that there is in preg_match and if its other charachters which is not allowed, then there must show up a error message that he need to type new username and he dont may allow go to chat if he dont have username with legal charaters. Thanks for your help btw, other idea to solve this one of your code?

Comment: You should be getting at least a page!  This is because of the if, else statement.  Then there must be a PHP error.  Does your PHP server suppress errors?

Comment: HAH! There was a syntax error..... Try the updated code. (Missing a paren on line 3)

Comment: =justderb, yes i have all enabled and he says this: Parse error: syntax error, unexpected '{' in /var/www/vhosts/futurechat.nl/httpdocs/chatlogin.php on line 5

Comment: The updated code should work, it runs correctly on my local set up.

Comment: =justderb Thank you very much!! That was a good lesson about Alternate Syntax, i will learn more about that.. Thank you for your time and effort and all other users here that did help. It works now as well!

Comment: Is it correct so? I did accept answer, if i'm right. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE: 
OP needs to detect invalid character, then, no need to match whole word, he is right with this pattern:

```
/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/
```

The real problem can be solved by removing this part of code:

```
$name = $_POST['name'];
if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/', $_POST['name']))
  echo "Invalid Username";
```

to beginning of the page:

```
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
  {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/', $_POST['name']))
      $error = "Invalid Username";
?>
```

Then you can echo `$error` inside body of the page any where

I will leave below answer also for general information.

---

You need to add `+` sign at the end of character group to match more than one charactor:

```
preg_match('/^[^A-Za-z0-9_-]+$/', $_POST['name'])
```

You pattern will match only one character any where, so that, you need also to add `^` at beginning and `$` at the end to match whole word

Comment: To add to this, always try and write regex expressions that are the most constrained you need them to be.  It will help tremendously in not allowing invalid inputs.

Comment: @Akam I got blank page, when i do that.

Comment: I can see that I am wrong in one principle, if you want to match invalid characters, then you are absolutely right when using `/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]`

Comment: @Akam i did try your new updated code, but he redirect me to chat again, so he dont check of illegal charaters, this is how i have him now:

`code`
<?php
  if(isset($_POST['submit'])) 
  {
    $name = $_POST['name'];
    if(preg_match('/[^A-Za-z0-9_-]/', $_POST['name']))
      $error = "Invalid Username";
?>
<html>
<head>

Comment: see other answer by 
justderb

Answer (score 0):

In your regular expression, the dash needs to be the first character in order to be used literally. See Also [Allow - (dash) in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833963/allow-dash-in-regular-expression)