# Matching bracketed numbers regex

Tags: python, regex

I am trying to extract all those numbers which are inside brackets as follows:

```
    [1]
    [3-13]
    [15]
    1
    2
    []
```

I intend to select the **FIRST THREE** in the above list. I want to grab

```
1
3-13
15
```

I am trying the following regex: `\[[\d*-\d*]\]`

I am testing out the regex in the [Link](http://pythex.org/?regex=%5C%5B%5B%5Cd*-%5Cd*%5D%5C%5D&test_string=%5B1%5D%0A%5B3-13%5D%0A%5B15%5D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0), but I get an error termed as "bad character range". What am I doing wrong? Please help. I am new to regex

Comment: Do this `\[[\d-]*\]`

Comment: You might need to escape the dash. Check out this answer
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833963/allow-dash-in-regular-expression

Comment: @mnciitbhu: worth noting that your regex would end up matching more than you'd expect (for example, `[-3-3-3]` or `[]`)

Comment: @Ekoji, what so you want to match from your input?

Comment: @nneonneo but it will match the first three in the question, as in question.

Comment: @mnciitbhu Actually, i found your answer to be precise. [-3-3-3] is irrelevant in this case

Comment: http://pythex.org/?regex=%5C%5B(%5B%5Cd-%5D%2B)%5C%5D&test_string=%5B1%5D%0A%5B3-13%5D%0A%5B15%5D%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A%5B%5D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Comment: What about this http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3C%3D%5C%5B)(%5B%5Cd-%5D%2B)(%3F%3D%5C%5D)&test_string=%5B1%5D%0A%5B3-13%5D%0A%5B15%5D%0A1%0A2%0A3%0A%5B%5D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0

Comment: @SIslam Yes, it works better. Why not answer it formally?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would try simple regex as-

```
(?<=\[)(([0-9]-*[0-9]*))(?=\])
```

Details

```
import re

s="""[1]
[3-13]
[15]
1
2
[3-3-3]
[-3-3-3]
[3-3-3-]
3
[]"""

data = re.findall(r'(?<=\[)(([0-9]-*[0-9]*))(?=\])',s)

print [i[0] for i in data]
```

Output-

```
['1', '3-13', '15']
```

<kbd>[DEMO](http://pythex.org/?regex=(%3F%3C%3D%5C%5B)((%5B0-9%5D-*%5B0-9%5D*))(%3F%3D%5C%5D)&test_string=%5B1%5D%0A%5B3-13%5D%0A%5B15%5D%0A1%0A2%0A%5B3-3-3%5D%0A%5B-3-3-3%5D%0A%5B3-3-3-%5D%0A3%0A%5B%5D&ignorecase=0&multiline=0&dotall=0&verbose=0)</kbd>
OR try <kbd>[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/qV7pG4/1)</kbd>

Answer (score 0):

This expression gets you any kind of number with in the list as a list of values, if you want to iterate over may be you can use `re.finditer`:

```
>>> print re.findall("\[(\d|\d[-]?\d+?)\]", "[1] [3-13] [15] 1 2 []")
['1', '3-13', '15']
```

**Edit**: Added right answer

Answer (score -1):

You don't want a character class `[]`, but rather a grouping operation `()`:

```
\[(\d+(?:-\d+)?)\]
```

Breaking this down:

- Outer () are capturing parens to grab exactly what you want
- `\d+` matches the first half of digits
- Inner `(?:)` are non-capturing parents
- `-\d+` matches a dash then the second half of digits
- Final `?` makes the second half (the inner group) optional