# Regex pattern throwing PatternSyntaxException in Java

Tags: java, regex, spring-boot

I have a regex pattern which checks for client auth domain name in certificate matching the pattern.
However it is throwing patternsyntax exception.

Pattern am using is below:

```
^(?!\s)([a-zA-Z0-9.-\s]{1,128})$
```

Exception is invalid character range near index 21. I suppose it is for -/s in the range. Is there a way to change the regex pattern? Can I use -/s at start of character range? Help would be appreciated.

Comment: This exact question has already been asked before [Allow - (dash) in regular expression](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8833963/allow-dash-in-regular-expression)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to escape the `-` symbol if you are trying to match it. So the correct regex would look as follow:

```
^(?!\s)([a-zA-Z0-9.\-\s]{1,128})$
```

I suggest you to use one of many online available [Regex tools](https://regexr.com/) when you want to learn and build your regex.